# Relative referencing files in folders instead of Main level in Haskell

Tags: file, haskell, file-handling

I've made a library, and I'm not using cabal for it (yet), so it's just as a folder next to main.hs source and stuff. When I put in one of my folders to use "Shaders/lt.frag" or even "Shaders"  "lt.frag", I get a openBinaryFile error, because there's no "Shaders/lt.frag" at the top level.

So it's look at "./Shaders/lt.frag", instead of "./Graphics/Lib/Rendering/Shaders/lt.frag". Any way to solve that? The file that references it is in "./Graphics/Lib/Rendering", so it should be relative to that.

Comment: In which way is this related to OpenGL? Yes, you're dealing with shader source files there, but this is ultimately just a Haskell I/O methodology problem. Removing that opengl tag, because it's irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought it -may- be an issue with how I'm loading the particular shaders. But you're right, it's ultimately just reading in contents from a text file. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're opening a file from within a Haskell program, then where the OS is looking for the file depends on the working directory of the program. Typically, the working directory of the program is the directory from which you invoke the executable, or the directory in which you execute GHCi.

The working directory has absolutely nothing to do with the directories where the individual Haskell source files reside.

Cabal indeed gives you [a way](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code) to place program data files into a particular location and get access to (the path of) that data directory while running the program.

Comment: If I were to use cabal, would the files in the package follow the same suit? So if I were to cabal up my code,  would it still look where my executable was? I'm not accessing the directory outside of my library.

Comment: It doesn't look where your executable is. The starting working directory of a program is the directory you call the executable from. You can get the current working directory using `System.Directory.getCurrentDirectory`. You can change it using `System.Directory.setCurrentDirectory`.

Comment: So if I were to try and use my files in the folder, I'd have to use setCurrentDirectory? Do you mind giving me a MWE? I'm not too sure I get it.

Comment: I still haven't really got an answer for this. I've now got a cabal library that reads in a file, but it needs to be in the working directory, etc. What would I do when reading in my file, so it looks relative to the library file?